# How to get the dynamic change of main modal from JS for checkbox in partial view .cshtml file (Knockout js)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a main view _New.cshtml and from this view I am calling a partial view _Contact.cshtml.

_New.cshtml

Here I have a checkbox for "Print" which is checked/unchecked based on parameter dataModel.Files([@i].IsPrint

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Files.Count; i++)
{
  <div>
    <strong>Print</strong>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: dataModel.Files() 
    [@i].IsPrint, value: dataModel.Files()[@i].IsPrint()" 
    id="IsPrint, click: getPrint.bind($data,@i)" name="Documents[@i].IsPrint" />
  </div>
  <div class="contactsgrid" data-bind="foreach: contacts">
    @{
             Html.RenderPartial("_Contact", Model);
     }
  </div>

}
```

_Contact.cshtml

I have a checkbox here also in which I have binded "IsEmail" from passed dataModel.

```
@{var v = Model.Files[Model.Index].Contacts[Model.Index].IsEmail ? "true" : "false";}
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:@v,click: $parent.getEmail.bind($data,@Model.Index)" />
```

new.js

Both the view's have common js file.

```
this.getEmail = function (index) {  
     if (dataModel.Files()[index].IsPrint() == true) {
             dataModel.Files()[index].IsPrint(false);      
         }
         else {
            dataModel.Files()[index].IsPrint(true);       
           }
           return true;
};
this.getPrint = function (index) {  
     if (dataModel.Files()[index].IsPrint() == true) {
             dataModel.Files()[index].Contacts()[index].IsEmail(false);   
         }
         else {
            dataModel.Files()[index].Contacts()[index].IsEmail(true);    
           }
   return true;
};
```

So, on click from checkbox in contact.cshtml I am changing the boolean value of IsPrint in the model for the corresponding index. Eventually it is getting checked or unchecked in the main View. But when I am trying to click on Is Print from main view and then updating the IsEmail value in js the model value change doesn't reflect in the partial view (checked:always stays the initial value)? How to get the scope of the model inside the partial view and get the parameters change dynamically?